# PHP and Classes: how can I use multiple Classes with only one instance?

Tags: php, class, methods, instance

I'm working on a new PHP Class. I've a single Class with some parameters, each of one will be an instance of classes, created separately into single PHP scripts.

So, I have:

```
    .- class.php
    |_ class.one.php
    |_ class.two.php
    |_ class.three.php
```

The first class, named head(), will have $arm, $foot and $body as parameters:

```
    Class Head {
        protected $arm;
        protected $foot;
        protected $body;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->arm = new Arm();
            $this->foot = new Foot();
            $this->body = new Body();
        }
    }

    $myHead = new Head();
    // with this instance, I can access to ALL classes instantiated before
```

Now, considering  the class Arm():

```
    Class Arm()
    {
        public function doSome()
        {
            echo "Cheers!";
        }
    }
```

and the class Foot():

```
    Class Foot()
    {
        public function doKick()
        {
            echo "GOAL!";
        }
    }
```

What I wish is to call the method doSome() from the method doKick().

Is this possible?

Comment: Probably possible with some convoluted hack, but you dont want to do that - using your body analogy, your foot does not control your arm. It reports back to your head, which might then choose to control your arm based on the response.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood classes here. `Foot` has absolutely no idea that a class called `Arm` even exists, so how can it call any method in that class?... you'd need to handle this through the co-ordinating `Head` class, in much the same way that reality does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have classes that are all completely separate from one another. They have nothing shared. If you extend a class from a parent to a child, the child knows everything about the parent (but the parent doesn't know anything changed in the child).

You could hack it and use a terrible work-around. What you should do is work on your design. Does Foot need to know about Arm? If so, then Foot must extend from Arm. Does that make sense? Not really. So, the fact that Foot is telling Arm to do something doesn't make sense. Perhaps Foot should contain an instance of Head. Arm can also. Then, Foot can tell Head that if there are any arms, they should do their thing. That, again, is a mess.

So, once again, you go back to the design. It really needs to be top down. When you can't work in a top-down way, you need to look into abstract methods and/or interfaces. An abstract method tells children to implement a method not implemented in the parent. Interfaces order a class to implement a set of methods so everyone knows the class will have those methods.

Comment: Ok, let's into the deep of this project. I need to create a Class to manage HTTP Request (GET/POST/etc.). for each request I need to made some execution with the other Classes (one for Authorization, one for Commons actions, another one for Reading/Writing/ into dB, and so on). Can I create some method into the Class Head() in order to execute some methods of other Classes?

Comment: Using your above code, a method in your `Head` class can call the `doKick()` method of the `Foot` class using `$this->foot->doKick();`